# where do I get cppcheck codeblocks plugin file?

Tags: ubuntu, codeblocks, cppcheck

I've installed code::blocks via ubuntu software center. I was never prompted anything, and the app was just installed.

The problem now is, that everywhere it says that `cppcheck` is integrated into code::blocks, but I don't see it anywhere. I've tried compiling the app with some obvious errors (returning local variable by reference), and there were no warnings or errors in the output.

Also, I don't seem to be able to find cppcheck.cbplugin anywhere.

Can anybody help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install package `codeblocks-contrib`. You also need to install
package `cppcheck` itself. Then, when you restart CB, **CppCheck** will
appear in the **Plugins** menu, and you can run it from there.

I do not recommend running it like this on a large project. It is liable to take a
very long time and freeze your desktop in the meanwhile. Better run it
independently in console.